# Issues in finding all simple paths between nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Is it feasible to find all simple paths between two nodes by using dijkstra algorithm on an unweighted graph. If yes,  how?

Comment: "*If yes..then how?*" No, to answer reasonably, we need your effort. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is intended for use in finding *shortest* paths.  You don't need it for finding *all* paths between two nodes.

Is this homework?

Comment: Is it ensured in your graph that the number of paths is even finite? (a DAG ensures that for example) Or are you interested in all *simple* paths, and not all paths?

Comment: @amit I am interested in simple paths, and yes my graph does contains cycles...but i m interested in getting all the simple paths between two nodes

Answer (score 0):

First of all dijkstra behaves just like Breadth-fist search on unweighted graph so it doesn't make any sense to use it for this task.

Typical way to get all paths between two vertices is using modified [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: @You talked about modified DFS...but the link u gave just talks about DFS....where exactly does DFS have to be modified to get all the paths between two vertices.

Comment: I guess you just need to find the number of times you encounter the vertex in a DFS?

Comment: @RoseBEck yes the link I sent is just about DFS. Your question is "Is it feasible to find..." so my answer is enough for that -no it is not feasible. As for the DFS algorithm I mention - you need to modify the way you mark a node as visited(as I am not sure if this is homework I am hesitant to give more detailed answer)

Comment: This is certainly not homework...i myself tried to modifying the algorithm by not marking the nodes as visited nodes...but the problem does not end here. I need to put back the visited nodes into the stack..as if i don't do so how would the nodes which have been visited earlier would be processed again...therefore I am requesting the exact modification.

Comment: Mark a node as visited on entrance in the recursive function and mark it as not visited on exit(last statement). This should do the trick\

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compute simple paths between any two nodes in a graph by using a modification of the standard Floyd-Warshall algorithm. You may want to check out [this](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=61)
problem from UVA Online Judge. Solution to it is freely available on the internet.